# How to select an image src with div id via javascript

Tags: javascript, image, select, src

For example I have this

```
 <div id="p22" class="ibox-content product-box" onclick="selectPlace('22')">
   <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/7LYKrgJm_cuZ5eldVYbPJBrp3ZI8I2jhtkBaLbKkLa0SYNxKqst4R22GKTQMrMVrhiNpMgQYlUcnG_7p=s0" alt="" class="image-create-site">
  <div id="check-p22" class="float-right top" style="display: none">
         <i class="float-right fa fa-check-circle fa-2x text-navy"></i>
            </div>
          <div class="product-desc">
        <span class="product-name"> 美容室 amor 水天宮前店（アモール）</span>
               </div>
                 </div>
```

These images are generated from an API and can change from time to time, so I need to get them based on the id of the div to send them through a form

in that example the id is "p22", can be obtained by calling to `selectedplace`

if I use `console.log(selectedPlace);` I get 22 on the console

Comment: Do you want to extract "22" from "p22" and pass it to `selectPlace`?

Comment: I want to extract the img src, the id from the div is p22, I get 22 if I use selectedPlace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also do this (simplier).

```
const target = document.querySelector("#p" + selectedPlace + ">img:first-child").src;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved using this

```
let imageSelected = document.getElementById('p' + selectedPlace).getElementsByTagName('img').item(0).getAttribute('src');
console.log(imageSelected);
```

It works with all IDs